# Does existence of a PDF imply the integrability of the characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

If the characteristic function of a random variable is integrable, then the random variable has a probability density function. Can anything be said about the other direction? That is, if a random variable has a probability density function (even a smooth one), is the characteristic function integrable or can anything at all be said about its decay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the characteristic function will not be integrable. Because if it was, it would follow (via Fourier inversion) that the PDF is actually a continuous function. So any discontinuous PDF (i.e. not a.e. to a continuous function) will do, for example $1_{[0,1]}$.

Conversely, a cheap criterion is the following: If the PDF $f$ has $k$ derivatives which are all integrable, then iterated partial integration shows

$$
g(\xi)=E(e^{i X \xi})=\int e^{i x \xi} f(x)\, dx = (-1)^k \cdot (i\xi)^k \cdot \int f^{(k)}(x) e^{i x \xi}\,dx. 
$$

Since characteristic functions are always bounded, this implies 
$$
|g(\xi)| \lesssim (1+|\xi|)^{-k},
$$
which for $k\geq 2$ yields integrability of the characteristic function.

Very similar arguments also hold in higher dimension.

What I used here is the general heuristic/fact  that smoothness of a function corresponds to decay of its Fourier transform.

Comment: I guess the powers of $k$ should be negative?

Comment: @Karen: Yes, you caught me. The power in the last display should have been negative (fixed now).

Comment: I have seen a result wich says that if the characteristic function of a bounded density function is non-negative then the characteristic function is integrable. I don't have a proof but I know a proof when the density is differentiable at 0.

Comment: @Kavi: Let $f$ denote the bounded (integrable) density. Let $\phi_\epsilon (x) = \epsilon^{-1} \cdot e^{-(x/\epsilon)^2}$. Consider $f_\epsilon = f \ast \phi_\epsilon$. Then the characteristic function of $f_\epsilon$ is $\hat{f_\epsilon}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) \cdot e^{- (\epsilon x)^2}$ (maybe I have some normalization wrong, but if $1 = 2\pi$, then everything should be alright :) ). Hence, $\hat{f_\epsilon} \in L^1$ is nonnegative. By Fourier inversion, we then get $\| \hat{f_\epsilon} \|_{L^1} = f_\epsilon (0) \leq \| f \|_{L^\infty}$. Then use Fatou's Lemma and send $\epsilon \downarrow 0$.